# Recreating this U-shape with cross walls

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, intersection

I asked a similar question before because I assumed I could figure out the rest by myself. Well, that didn't really work out, and I am once again asking for your support.

How would I go about creating this object in Blender? I tried putting in the walls separately, but that's obviously not the correct approach. Do I extrude them from the walls of the U-shape? ...

Any help is much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: instead of asking again "from zero" you should exactly specify what you couldn't do because you did accept the answer from Robin. So sorry...i can only vote to close this question due to lack of details

Comment: Hello, @Chris .. to be fair, the diagonal struts make this a very different case?  (If anything, it shows the limitations of the smarty-pants Modifier approach)  :)

Comment: @Chris I assumed this question might need a completely different approach than simply creating the U-shape from my previous question. I tried putting in the walls separately, but that's obviously not the solution. And before fiddling around too much, I thought I'd ask for the "right" way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

You could begin with this Z shape that you mirror:

[image]

Array with the *Array* modifier:

[image]

Bend it with the *Simpled Deform* in *Bend* mode and you are almost good:

[image]

Comment: Interesting approach! I'll try and see if I can end up with the desired result. Thank you!